# Cakephp make child array editable

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

My model is a user which can have multiple Email addresses. I can view them by:

```
 <?php  foreach ($user->email_addresses as $addresses): ?>
    <tr>
            <td><?=  h($addresses->id) ?></td>
            <td><?=  h($addresses->email) ?></td>
    </tr>
 ?>
```

I try to make them editable as input but is does not work:

```
 <?php  foreach ($user->email_addresses as $addresses): ?>
    <tr>
           <td><?= $this->Form->control('addresses.id'); ?></td>
           <td><?= $this->Form->control('addresses.email'); ?></td>
    </tr>
 ?>
```

Comment: Looks like your relation means that the inputs should be named with `email_addresses.xxx`, not `addresses.xxx`.

Comment: tried that already

Comment: [**`email_addresses.index.property`**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data)

Comment: also doesn't work

Comment: It will work when done correctly... please show what you've tried.

Comment: i tried different things eg. `email_addresses.index.email` `user.email_addresses.index.email` `addresses.index.email` also with `$index`

Comment: ah:    `<?= $this->Form->control('email_addresses.'.$index.'.email') ?>` is right

Comment: but now I have the problem that edited fields are added on save

Comment: also solved: i had to add the id control

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  foreach ($user->email_addresses as $index=>$addresses): ?>
    <tr>

        <td>
            <?= $this->Form->control('email_addresses.'.$index.'.id') ?>
            <?= $this->Form->control('email_addresses.'.$index.'.email') ?>
```